# SWT : What are the differences between Dialog and Window and when should one use which?

Tags: java, swt, jface

Not sure about which one to use when and their differences

I tried browsing the internet but didn't get any answer

Comment: `org.eclipse.jface.window.Window` is [tag:jface] not basic SWT. If you are writing a SWT only app you can't use it. There two `Dialog` classes - there is `org.eclipse.swt.Dialog`, and `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog` - which one are you asking about.

Comment: Hi Greg, the doubt is when to use org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog or org.eclipse.jface.window.Window ?

Answer (score 1):

`org.eclipse.jface.window.Window` just gives you a window with no special contents.

`org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog` (which extends Window) is intended for dialogs and by default creates OK and Cancel buttons. Also by default it is "application modal" so everything else is blocked while it is open. Most parts of the dialog's behaviour can be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with:

org.eclipse.jface.window.Window just gives you a window with no special contents.

org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog (which extends Window) is intended for dialogs and by default creates OK and Cancel buttons. Also by default it is "application modal" so everything else is blocked while it is open. Most parts of the dialog's behaviour can be overridden.

I think windows are particularly useful when you want to create your own custom output display. Dialogs are usually used when you want input from a user or when you want to display something like an error message. The fact that a dialog comes with OK and Cancel buttons means that it is easy to use and it is a fast solution whereas windows can do the same but they require more effort to be created and implemented.